# SQL: Update a field by its related rows?

Tags: sql

I have the following schema:

**Product**:

```
  id: int pk ai
  title: string
  available: int
  left: int
```

**Order**:

```
  id: int pk ai
  status: int
```

**OrderItem**:

```
  id: int pk ai
  order_id: int fk Order.id
  product_id: int fk Product.id
  amount: int
```

So, when products are purchased, an order is created, with one or more order items. The status of the order indicates whether the order has been completed.

I need to update the 'left' field of all products. It should be calculated by summing up all the product amounts in `order_items`, for orders that have a certain status (e.g. status=2), and subtracting the result from the 'available' value in the `Products` table (that is, if a product has 10 available, and there is one completed order listing that product with amount=3, the resulting `left` should become 7.)

Ideally, I would like to do this using one SQL query.

Comment: search on here for "update with join", have a go, and you'll be able to answer @Michael Todd

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple.. just do one thing take the sum of amount from table Order_item where OrderId from Order table has status = 2 (I suppose this is code for complete status) well this you need to subtract from available value. below is the query for this -

```
update Product p
set `left` = available - (select sum(amount) 
                          from orderItem oi, `order` o
                         where oi.order_id = o.id
                           and product_id = p.id
                           and o.status = 2
                           )
```

this should update your Product table as you wanted.

Comment: I'll play around with this solution this evening. (I did edit your answer to backquote identifiers that are reserved SQL words.)